# What's the best practice for running multiple tasks in iOS blocks and queues?

Tags: ios, performance, cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I've started to use blocks and queues heavily and they have been great. I use much less code and it is much easier to build and maintain. But I wonder about performance. In one case I am displaying a screen full of thumbnail images from a Flickr photo set. The code iterates over all items and starts a unique download queue to download each photo concurrently. It's working just fine, but I wonder if I should instead create a single static queue for downloading photos and then dispatch these download blocks to the same queue so that it can manage the blocks efficiently.

I've uploaded an example here.

http://www.smallsharptools.com/Downloads/iOS/UIImage+DownloadImage.zip

The implementation contents are also below. I appreciate any insight into better performance. (Later I'd like to handle caching for images by placing the file in the tmp folder so they are automatically cleared out periodically.)

How do you manage concurrent tasks with blocks? Do you create a static queue and dispatch blocks to the shared queue? Or does the implementation below implicitly manage all of my tasks efficiently already?

```
#import "UIImage+DownloadImage.h"

@implementation UIImage (DownloadImage)

+ (void)downloadImageWithURL:(NSURL *)imageURL andBlock:(void (^)(UIImage *image, NSError *error))returnImage {

    dispatch_queue_t callerQueue = dispatch_get_current_queue();
    dispatch_queue_t downloadQueue = dispatch_queue_create("Image Download Queue", NULL);
    dispatch_async(downloadQueue, ^{
        UIImage *image = nil;
        NSError *error = nil;

        // use the default cache policy to do the memory/disk caching
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest 
                                        requestWithURL:imageURL 
                                        cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy 
                                        timeoutInterval:15];

        NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSData *data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

        // 200 indicates HTTP success
        if (response.statusCode != 200) {
            data = nil;

            // set the error to indicate the request failed
            NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Request failed with HTTP status code of %i", response.statusCode], NSLocalizedDescriptionKey, nil];
            error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"UIImage+DownloadImage" code:response.statusCode userInfo:userInfo];
        }
        else if (!error && data) {
            image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        }

        // image will be nil if the request failed

        dispatch_async(callerQueue, ^{
            returnImage(image, error);
        });
    });
    dispatch_release(downloadQueue);
}

@end
```

Comment: I've already commented on the notion of re-invoking `dispatch_queue_create()` for each image. Seems like you should do that only once. Also, since you ask about best practices, Apple advises that you should use reverse DNS notation when naming your queues (e.g. "com.mycompany.myqueue").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does seem inefficient to create a 1-element queue each time, though I would be surprised if this would show up as a hotspot during profiling.

If you search on Apple's iOS forums, you should be able to find Quinn's discussion of using NSURLConnection "raw" rather than via threads.

Comment: +1, downloads should be done using the asynchronous API, and if I could I'd give another +1 for mentioning Quinn "The Eskimo!"

Comment: I have used the async API but now I do not have to due to GCD and blocks which is shown in this example. I run the download on an async queue so the UI stays responsive. And working with blocks is more elegant than implementing many methods and managing variables. Also could not find that Quinn discussion. There are many to choose from on there.

Comment: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/9606?tstart=0 (it's pinned to the top of its category).

Comment: Thanks for the link. Quinn really digs deep into the details that I do not have. I still want to know if there would be a difference if the queue I use is static so all blocks run on a single queue, ignoring the networking part. I still want to use blocks/queues in various ways like this.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing synchronous network activity on queues. This seems like a rather poor idea, since you're blocking threads and forcing GCD to spin up new threads to service other blocks. If you're downloading 20 images simultaneously, then you will have 20 blocked threads in your app and another handful to actually do work. Instead you should be doing asynchronous network activity on a single worker thread. There's even a piece of Apple sample code that does this, though I cannot for the life of me remember what it's called.

Comment: Do you have a reason to say that doing network activity in a queue is a bad idea? Isn't everything run on a queue and could be blocked at any time? I suppose I could run these network requests on a lower priority queue, but so far it seems to work rather well. I just wonder if I should use a single queue for all 20 requests. I'll have to experiment and profile it.

Comment: @Brennan: You're doing blocking IO, specifically network IO, on a queue. You're blocking the *entire* thread when you do that and you're forcing GCD to spin up new threads (which is expensive). There's absolutely no reason to perform this *flagrant* waste of resources when you can run all your network activity on a single thread.

Comment: My two cents: @Brennan, doing network IO on separate queue is not only not bad idea, but it's good. I think Kevin is suggesting that it's not smart to call `dispatch_queue_create()` for each image. You should create single queue, and then go ahead and do your `dispatch_async()` to that queue.